# Add Date Condition to Macro, to determine what to copy

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sales commission report that I built a small macro for. The macro is working fine. It copies the required info from the one sheet and posts to the "summary" sheet.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub Test()

Dim r As Long

r = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)

Sheets("Comm Payable").Range("C31:P31").Copy
Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & r).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Comm Payable").Range("C3:D3").Copy
Sheets("Summary").Range("B" & r).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Comm Payable").Range("N1").Copy
Sheets("Summary").Range("C" & r).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Comm Payable").Range("O1").ClearContents

End Sub
```

I need assistance for the section of code that deals with range "C32:P32":

```
Sheets("Comm Payable").Range("C31:P31").Copy
Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & r).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

I have 12 rows "A20:A31". A20 is Jan-19, A21 is Feb-19, and so on.

At the moment the macro just copies C31:P31, but what I need it to do is to copy from C to P, but based on the date in say N1. If N1 is "April 2019", then it must find the row in "A" that is "Apr-19" and copy that C:P.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your code. It loops through the cells in the A column for the date in the N1 and copies the row if it finds it.

```
Dim aDate As Date
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Comm Payable").Range("A20:A31")
aDate = Sheets("Comm Payable").Range("N1")
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value = aDate Then
        rownum = cell.Row
        Sheets("Comm Payable").Range("C" & rownum & ":P" & rownum).Copy
        Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & r).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
Next cell
```